# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0

Tags: c#

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

it running on my local pc but when upload to server then they cause error.

Comment: log4net is a logging app.  Your program is trying to run it.  You have it installed, its probably in your bin directory but its not on the server.  Copy it there.

Comment: log4net dll has strong name, you must use the same version of dll as the one that your app requires it at compile time.

Comment: paqogomez what can installed to foe log4net dll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673383/error-could-not-load-log4net-assembly

Comment: linquize where i found this dll

Comment: @user3418604 - As paqogomez said, try looking in your bin directory. Otherwise use the Search feature of OS

Comment: How to download this dll to add ref in proj pls. send me link

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have **log4net dll** in your **bin** folder.

Comment: I know for this but i cannot find this dll 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0 pls. send link ti download this dll

Comment: @user3418604 : Try modifying your config with your version of log4net dll you have.

Comment: @ csLijo  But Where I found This Dll

Comment: i download this add dll in bin folder but same prob occured

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `32bit` log4net dll then you will need to `enable APP pool of your IIS to run in 32bit mode`.

[image]

Comment: @user3418604 Then make sure **Enable 32-Bit Application** property is set to **false**